# Does Apple provide replacement tips for their In-Ear Headphones?

Tags: headphones

One of my earbud tips has been lost. I'd like to replace it. I'd prefer not to use a third-party service, as the quality of the material is never as high as Apple's.

Do you know if Apple will replace them?

Comment: Sorry, but your question seems strange. You want to replace something that you lost? That's your own fault. Apple will not replace losses. You might get a missing earbud for free or have to buy replacement earbuds.

Answer (score 1):

I know it used to be not a big hassle to change them. You could just send them to Apple and a few days later, the new earbuds arrived. But since many people took advantage of this system, Apple came up with a limit (both in quantity as in warranty time).

Now days, my best guess is to go to the Apple Store and ask if they will replace it.

But why would you exclude non-Apple earbuds? There are some very good (and cheap) ones. For example on [DealExtreme](http://dx.com/c/iphone-ipad-ipod-299/earphones-207) or even on eBay.

Answer (score 0):

Yes - call Apple Support, open a web ticket or visit a reseller or an Apple Store. The service departments can order replacement silicone cups if they don't just have them in stock.

[image: the full set of six cups]

Comment: If someone has a better picture than the one I copped from amazon, pls upload. :-)